# Asterisk Priorities that have a possibility of matching

Tags: asterisk

I want to be able to isolate only toll free numbers from my dialplan and route then through SIP instead of through a local trunk.  My question is the priority numbering and it seems the toll free number would also match up with the trunk extension.

Currently:
`

```
 exten => _1XXXXXXXXXX,1,SetCallerID(${DEFAULT_CIDName} <${DEFAULT_CIDNum}>)

 exten => _1XXXXXXXXXX,n,Dial(${TRUNK_OB}/${EXTEN:0:11})

 exten => _1XXXXXXXXXX,n,Hangup
```

`

I want to be able to add:

`exten => _1800NXXXXXX,1,Dial(SIP/sip.server.com/${EXTEN})`

(as well as 888, 855, 877 & 866)

but the toll free number matches the trunk Dial as well.

If I set the addition as Priority 2 and then set the trunk dial as Priority 3, would it only dial the SIP and skip the trunk or is it possible to have them both as Priority 1 and then if it's a toll free, only dial the SIP?

I have looked everywhere and can not come up with the conclusion. Any advice would be greatly appreciated!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your example you overwrite priority 1 and dialplan continues with priority 2 within the "broader" extension pattern. In your case, when you dial 18001234567, the following dialplan will execute:

```
exten => _1800NXXXXXX,1,Dial(SIP/sip.server.com/${EXTEN})
exten => _1XXXXXXXXXX,2,Dial(${TRUNK_OB}/${EXTEN:0:11})
exten => _1XXXXXXXXXX,3,Hangup
```

The SetCallerID() is overwritten by the toll-free extension. There are two ways to solve this problem:

1. Overwrite extension 2, not 1

   ```
   exten => _1XXXXXXXXXX,1,SetCallerID(${DEFAULT_CIDName} <${DEFAULT_CIDNum}>)
   exten => _1XXXXXXXXXX,n,Dial(${TRUNK_OB}/${EXTEN:0:11})
   exten => _1XXXXXXXXXX,n,Hangup
   ; overwrite priority 2 (Dial) for toll free numbers
   exten => _1800NXXXXXX,2,Dial(SIP/sip.server.com/${EXTEN})
   ```

   This may not be the cleanest solution as you will get confused by priorites when moving code around.
2. Set a "dialstring" variable in priority 1 which you can overwrite and use later.

   ```
   exten => _1XXXXXXXXXX,1,Set(DIALOUTSTRING=${TRUNK_OB}/${EXTEN:0:11})
   exten => _1XXXXXXXXXX,n,SetCallerID(${DEFAULT_CIDName} <${DEFAULT_CIDNum}>)
   exten => _1XXXXXXXXXX,n,Dial(${DIALOUTSTRING})
   exten => _1XXXXXXXXXX,n,Hangup
   ; use another dialout for toll free numbers
   exten => _1800NXXXXXX,1,Set(DIALOUTSTRING=SIP/sip.server.com/${EXTEN})
   ```